# He is watching the TV upside down

Tags: grammar

He was laying on the floor and watched the TV.

(Body on top and back on bottom)

> He is watching the TV upside down

his sister told me.

Can I use upside down for the posture below?

[image]

Comment: I suggest using the following to provide depiction, "His view of the television is upside-down."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may, it is quite clear what you mean.

There is potential ambiguity (is it him who is upside-down or the TV?). You could also say "He watched the TV lying on his back" but it is less obvious that the picture on the TV would appear inverted.